# Is it possible to implement SSL (wss://) using PHP socket extension?

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, websocket

I have a websocket server, implemented using PHP's `socket` library, and all works well... provided you are using the `ws://` protocol.

However, we now need to upgrade the library to work over SSL, i.e. to support the `wss://` protocol.

Is it possible to implement `wss://` (or more generally, I suppose, SSL connections) using the PHP [`socket`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) functions, or will we need to rewrite the code to use the [`stream_socket`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php) functions?

*(Note that there may be other good reasons to switch to `stream_socket`, so regardless of the answer we may consider doing that anyway.  However, before I spend time evaluating the two options, I want to confirm that sticking with `socket` is even an option for us.)*

Comment: FWIW, SSL should be terminated by the web server or even earlier (e.g. proxy, load balancer), application code should not need to be burdened with worrying about such details.

Comment: We are talking about the web server (or websocket server, in this case), which is implemented in PHP.  There may or may not be proxies/load balancers in front of it, but for most of our deployments there are not.

Comment: I'd manage this with something like nginx *in front* of PHP, or since most of my stuff these days runs on AWS, an AWS load balancer which will manage the certificates for me. Just saying, I find such separation of concerns beneficial.

Comment: One common way of adding SSL/TLS to services that don't support it would be stunnel. This offloads the need for you to support it in your websocket server. More info... https://www.stunnel.org/

Comment: All true, but not relevant to my question.  We develop the software, but often don't control the deployment environment.

Comment: It is possible to do but requires you to implement a lot of things that are already done for you when using `stream_socket` functions.

Comment: @BA_Webimax - Care to submit that as an answer?  A bit more detail would be good, but even as it stands it would be something I could accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm submitting an answer on behalf of [@BA_Webimax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895481/ba-webimax) who posted what is probably the correct answer in a comment, but hasn't returned to make that into an answer that I can accept.

So as a direct answer to the question "Is it possible?":

> It is possible to do but requires you to implement a lot of things that are already done for you when using stream_socket functions.
>
> -- [@BA_Webimax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895481/ba-webimax)

To flesh that out a bit further, it would mean handling all of the SSL negotiation and encryption manually.  This would be a fair amount of work, require a lot of testing and runs the risk of introducing security holes if not implemented exactly right.

Rewriting the code to use the stream_socket functions is likely to be quicker, safer and more robust.

So, whilst the technical answer is yes, it is possible, the pragmatic answer is probably no, it is not.